# Автоматический перерасчет цены заказа при его изменении в админке django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет.
Сайт транспортной компании.

1. При редактировании заказа в админке, после его сохранения, срабатывает сигнал (заказ изменен).
2. Далее включается перерасчет итоговой цены в этом заказе и перезапись ее.
3. После перезаписи опять срабатывает сигнал (заказ изменен) и получается рекурсия.

Подскажите логическую схему, как реализовать пересчет итоговой цены после изменения заказа (корректируются вес и размер груза).

Comment: Судя по логике в п.3 сравнивается с данными до пересчёта. Необходимо их (условие) обновлять, тогда сигнал не будет срабатывать.

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, то вы повесили сигнал на метод save, а функция которая при этом вызывается также использует метод save, так почему же не засунуть пересчет цены в метод save при каждом её вызове,  и отказаться от использования сигнала?

Comment: Вы говорите про метод save, который переопределяется в модели? Попробовал сейчас этот способ, там при расчете используются данные из других моделей и джанго ругается на циклический импорт.

Comment: сложно понять не видя кода. каким образом импорт зацикливается? если для расчета цены используются другие модели то это не проблема на мой взгляд, вы же не их перезаписываете, а просто получаете текущее значение данных.

Comment: в отдельном файле calculator.py импортируются модели, которые используются в функции calculator_order для расчета итоговой стоимости. В models.py я импортирую эту функцию calculator_order из calculator.py  и получается циклический импорт.

Comment: так я  о том и говорю: в методе save написать функцию calculator а не импортировать её.

Comment: Возможно так и придется сделать, не хочется дублировать код калькулятора еще и в модели. Он так же используется в калькуляторе расчета на сайте, там просто идет расчет без сохранения в базу. Поэтому я вынес его в отдельный файл.

Comment: Нет, он также используется в калькуляторе на сайте. Посетители могут рассчитать доставку без оформления заказа.

Comment: Второе использование: В определенный момент менеджер вносит изменения в заказ через админку и он должен пересчитать стоимость.

Comment: как вариант написать функцию calculator_order которая будет принимать необходимые параметры на вход а не запрашивать их из базы данных. Таким образом можно избежать цикла.

Comment: Буду пробовать. Спасибо за помощь!